# Prevent Chrome 80 from freezing tab with my page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a simple html page that displays some monitoring results, it reloads every 2 minutes and makes noise when those results are not acceptable. I keep this page open 24/7, so new Chrome started freezing and suspending it, as I found out via chrome://discards/ .. So the page stopped making noise and catching my attention, mostly cause the tab gets frozen by Chrome. That happens if I forget to leave the tab with this page active, "on top". Is there a rather simple way to prevent Chrome from freezing the tab, even if it is not active? I could involve some Javascript, if needed..

I am aware that there is a simple solution of opening new window with this page and leaving it alone. On the other hand, I made the page, so I can make changes to HTML in order to ensure that page remains unfrozen. I tried updating title with current time on every reload, this visibly helped, page seemingly always has fresh time in the title, but it still doesn't make noise. And if I switch into it when noise is supposed to happen, - it starts the sound half way like it was trying to all alone.. it's even funny..

Is there any simple solution to this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this addon: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok